# Does duplication of BLOB value from JOIN in SELECT query significantly affect performance?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, blob

The case I am concerned with is the following. There are three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Transaction(
  Id DECIMAL(13,0),
  User_Name CHAR(50)
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
--
CREATE TABLE Attachment(
  Id DECIMAL(13, 0),
  Transaction_Id DECIMAL(13, 0),
  Description CHAR(200),
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Transaction_Id) REFERENCES Transaction(Id)
);
--
CREATE TABLE Transaction_Data(
  Transaction_Id DECIMAL(13, 0),
  Json BLOB(32M),
  PRIMARY KEY (Transaction_Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Transaction_Id) REFERENCES Transaction(Id)
);
```

For each transaction, there can be 0 or more attachments, and 0 or only one JSON written in BLOB. I need to get all data related to a particular transaction. For this purpose, I wrote the following SELECT query:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.User_Name, a.Id, a.Description, d.Json
FROM Transaction t
LEFT JOIN Attachment a
    ON a.Transaction_Id = t.Id
LEFT JOIN Transaction_Data d
    ON d.Transaction_Id = t.Id
WHERE t.Id = 100;
```

In the resulting table, I get BLOB value (JSON) duplicated as many times as there are attachments for the transaction. I need to use the result set in my Java application. The application communicates with database remotely. So, my question is, does the mentioned duplication of BLOB value in result set affect the amount of data transferred via the network, and what is the common practice for dealing with such cases?

I am using IBM DB2 database, and driver db2jcc4-4.9.78, or Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>db2jcc4</groupId>
  <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
  <version>4.9.78</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hint: try to ask **one** question per question, not 5.

Comment: Edited the question as suggested to ask the most relevant thing :)

Comment: The Data will only bei fetched if you read the InputStream

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I am using IBM DB2, and the driver db2jcc4-4.9.78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the mentioned duplication of BLOB value in result set affect the amount of data transferred via the network

Answers to JDBC questions like this very often depend on the actual implementation of the particular JDBC driver. Without knowing what JDBC driver you are using I cannot say for sure whether the duplication *will* affect the volume of data transferred over the wire, but a quick test showed that it most certainly *can* affect that volume.

I created a table named `transaction_data` in MySQL with a 1.7 MB LONGBLOB in a column named `json`. I created a little Java test to query that database using mysql-connector-java-5.1.41 with the default connection properties, ResultSet attributes, etc.. Also worth mentioning is that I just did `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()`; I did not loop through the ResultSet and explicitly retrieve the `json` value(s) using `getBlob`. (In fact, I didn't retrieve any values from the ResultSet at all.)

When I executed a SELECT query that affected a transaction with one (1) attachment so the related `json` value is included in just one row, Wireshark told me that the total network traffic for that query (both directions) was 1877488 bytes, or 1.8 MB.

After adding nine (9) more attachments to that transaction so the related `json` value was included in ten (10) rows, Wireshark told me that the total network traffic for that query (both directions) was 18766790 bytes, or 17.9 MB.

So yes, in this case the duplicated `json` BLOB was pulled over the wire ten (10) times.

Now MySQL Connector/Java is somewhat famous for its default behaviour of "slurping" the entire ResultSet down to the client in one shot, so other JDBC drivers might act differently. You probably should do a little testing with the actual JDBC driver you intend to use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with the situation? :) Is applying UNION clause proper in such case?

Comment: @ArtursSolomencevs - You could execute two separate queries: one to retrieve the BLOB object and the other to retrieve the multi-row data.